# Searching network devices for smb1 using powershell

Tags: powershell, smb

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature –Online –FeatureName SMB1Protocol
```

Will tell me if the machine I run it on is running smbv1

Can this be somehow modified to run on remote machines? I have about 1000 servers, 6000 workstations, and 10,000+ IoT/Network devices (though, they're not running windows).

I know packet capturing is the typical method, however I don't really have a central choke-point to put a packet analyzer in my environment.

Comment: take a look at using `Invoke-Command` to run a scriptblock against a list of systems. if you give I-C a list of computers in the `-ComputerName` parameter, it will run the scriptblock _remotely on each system, in parallel_. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with nmap + powershell

```
$NmapFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "U:\nmap reports\Nmap Subnet 
Scans\September2019" -Recurse -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$data = ForEach ($item in $NmapFolder){
$Subnet = $item.Name.replace('_','/')
write-host "scanning"$Subnet". Please wait..."
nmap -p 445 --script smb-protocols -oN "U:\\nmap reports\\Nmap Subnet Scans\\September2019\\$item\\SMB_results.nmap" $Subnet
write-host "Done, report written for"$Subnet". Report has been written to: U:\\nmap reports\\Nmap Subnet Scans\\September2019\\"$item"\\SMB_results.nmap"
}
```

I made a folder (September2019) that contains a bunch of folders named after my subnets:

> 10.0.0.0_23
>
> 10.10.10.0_24
>
> 10.100.10.0_24

etc. I have a bout 120 local subnets in my organization.

I then change `_` to `/` (Windows folder names can't have `/`)

Now I have a CIDR notation that I can throw at nmap.

Nmap has a script to analyze a target for SMB, and it'll tell me what versions it's running.

The output for the whole subnet goes into it's respective folder, and move to the next.

I'll write another script to parse all of the results and only show me targets that have SMB1 enabled.